# How to make storyboard size looks like in 4.7" inch aspect ratio

Tags: ios, xcode6

My storyboard's aspect ratio looks more like  a square.

And when I deployed it to simulator,

The position was not as my expectation.

How to fix it ?

I want the storyboard's content can be look the same as my iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

New Storyboards and Xibs created in [xcode6](/questions/tagged/xcode6) have *"Size Classes"* enabled by default. This causes the Scene to become a devise agnostic square shape.

You can turn off *Size Classes* by unchecking the checkbox in the Interface Builder Document section of the File Inspector tab of the Utilities panel.

[image: Utilities panel > File Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Select the ViewController in StoryBoard open Utilities pan -->select Attributes inspector -->Simulated Metrics --> Size - inferred(default) change it to your required size.

[image]

Comment: i answered for "How to make storyboard size looks like in 4.7" inch aspect ratio",what these down voters think....?

Comment: Because you change it on a "per view basis". The real question is : how to make it 4.7 inch for the whole storyboard, to keep the "inferred" size if possible. I won't downvote you, but it's still not the answer I'm looking for ^_^ (I have the same issue as @user3675188)